# NLP - 'SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit' / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to write a hate speech detection code but i am stuck with a problem. I am getting the error  `SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit'` I am looking from source which used python 2 but I am using python 3 maybe the problem occurs because of this but I couldn't solve this. How can I fix this problem ?

```
training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features, train_tweets)

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier

# SKlearn Wrapper
classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())

classifier.fit(X_train, X_test)

predicted_labels = [classifier.classify(extract_features(tweet[0])) for tweet in test_tweets]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but this documentation mentions a function called "train" instead of "fit"; maybe that's your issue: https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html

Also, are you sure passing the second argument (X_test) is correct here? It's not normal with classifiers, as you should only be passing the training data in that step, and the documentation doesn't mention it either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, it should be `classifier.train([X_train, y_train])`

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it should work:

## SKlearn Wrapper

classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())

classifier = classifier.fit(X_train, X_test)

Comment: also, it should be (x_train,y_train) as Christoph pointed out.